# Floor and ceiling Functions in Inequalities

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inequality

Let a and b be real numbers with a < b. how do I Use the floor and/or ceiling functions to express the number of integers n that satisfy a ≤ n ≤ b?

Since we know that x ≤ n if and only if ⌈x⌉ ≤n ( n integer ). And we know that x ≤ n if and only if n ≤ ⌊x⌋ ( n integer )

⌈a⌉ ≤ n ≤ ⌊b⌋ , but i am not sure where to do from here?

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is fully correct : the integers comprised between $a$ and $b$ shall respect the inequality $⌈a⌉ ≤ n ≤ ⌊b⌋$.
The number of the integers satisfying that will be $ ⌊b⌋-⌈a⌉+1$, provided that $a \le b$.

Comment: why did you add one though? ⌊b⌋−⌈a⌉+1,

Comment: @xander: because both extremes are included

Comment: what do you mean?